# Rubymine with ruby 2.6.6 don't run the project

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I tried to run Rubymine with ruby ​​2.6.6, it creates the project but when and all but when I tried to view the site (run configuration) on the browser I write 100 error lines, when I run with ruby ​​2.7.5 it doesn't I make no mistake.

Comment: Do you manage to run the Rails server without RubyMine (via Terminal)?

Comment: no i dont know how to do it, and if i understand it well i have downloaded only ruby the rest is rubymine

Comment: RubyMine helps to create a Rails project by running the corresponding commands, but still it uses Rails: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.